# is <script>javascript:alert(document.domain); a valid script for xss?

Tags: xss, javascript

I have submit the following text `<script>javascript:alert(document.domain);` in a feedback of a restaurant listed on a website and feedback is sent to website not restaurant.

I want to verify but I am not sure if the code is valid or not according to javascript.

Comment: Have you tried an online javascript interpreter? Do you see that the syntax is not complete for Javascript? What have you done to attempt to verify that this code is valid?

Comment: I'm not an XSS guru, but I thought it was simply `<script>alert(document.domain)</script>`

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax will look something like this `<script>alert(document.domain)</script>`
, since if you do not close the script tag your script will continue to pickup anything that is after it and can mess up the execution

I recommend trying these in your own environment to get familiar, perhaps try out DVWA.

Comment: Welcome to the community. An alternative to DVWA (more modern) is OWASP Juice Shop but it uses the MEAN stack.

Comment: Thank you!
Oh yeah I tried that one a while ago, I liked it